# how can Use the title 'Mr'

Tags: word-choice, expressions, meaning-in-context, parts-of-speech, possessive-determiners

Use of titles in English language, can we use title Mr if we use the designation like Secretary Sports Mr Saleem Akhtar, etc, or we skip it. i am asking in reference to make a news report or news article.

Comment: With a higher title already, the less prestigous title is normally skipped. e.g. "President Barack Obama", "Secretary of State John Kerry". If you want to add "Mr." or "Madam/Mrs./Ms./Miss" (for a woman) you would place it first. e.g. "Mr. President Barack Obama", "Madam Governor Sarah Palin" / "Mrs. Governor Sarah Palin". If you want to write "Mr" next to the name *and* title then you should use a comma, "(the) President, Mr. Barack Obama" or "Secretary of State, Mr. John Kerry"

Comment: Note: “Secretary Sports” is not a title. It’s what secretaries do for exercise in their free time. The title would be “Secretary _of_ Sports”.

Comment: You can only drop a formal title if you know someone personally.

Answer (score 1):

If you are aiming for a very formal report then you can use Secretary of Sports, Mr Saleem Akhtar. If you aren't being that formal, then Secretary of Sports, Saleem Akhtar is acceptable. You will often see the latter in newspapers in the UK.

Comment: Don't they use a '.' in the UK?         (Mr. Saleem Akhtar)

Comment: @BrianHitchcock In general, no. The rule taught by most (or at least many) teachers in the UK is that an abbreviation does not take a period if it ends in the last letter of the original word; thus _Mr_, _Mrs_, and _Dr_, but _M._ for _Monsieur_ and _Prof._ for _Professor_.

Comment: They should, but it seems that this is being ignored ever more frequently. A quick scan through a few papers shows that only The Telegraph uses the format Mr. Saleem Akhtar - the others (where they use the title at all) go for Mr Saleem Akhtar. Again, I suspect it's a matter of how formal you wish to sound.

Comment: I don't think that's how the Q runs, between formal and informal. The OP asks whether the title *Mr.* can go **along with** a designation.

Comment: Which is what I answered in my first response. I was adding a little more depth to explain why there is a difference, and I apologise if that has resulted in confusion.

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet: thank you. One learns something new every day.  (Earlier today I learned what a "numpty" is.)  So, the no-dot rule would apply to Jr, Sr, Msgr, Fr? ( Not sure if the last of these means "Father", "Friar" or both).  And I was also surprised to find BrE apparently does not put a dot after first and/or middle initials.  https://www.kcs.org.uk/senior-school/staff     Is this typical in BrE?